# Extract data to SQL Server table from Sharepoint list using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have to insert data into a SQL Server table. My source (Sharepoint) and destination (SQL Server), field names are different from source to destination. Also, I have 300 columns at destination and 350 columns in source. How to handle this and map the fields?

I went through this code link but am getting an error on column mapping:
[Using a Console App to Extract a data from sharepoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914555/using-a-console-app-to-extract-a-data-from-sharepoint-list)

I have built ssis component using above link. But am getting an error

> column mapping fields error

Comment: Check the following post, it may hepls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476238/sql-server-connecting-to-sharepoint-server/56485677#56485677

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSIS to create a dataflow from Sharepoint to SQL and still getting the column mapping fields error, check the datatype mapping between source and destination components. If you're unable to check all the fields, you can set to redirect rows into a separate component and verify the fields and datatypes to identify the columns that might be causing data conversion issues.

To configure the error output, right click on the source component and go to advanced settings and set the column redirect rows when there is a truncation error.
[Configure Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox0CO.png)

Comment: I'm using script task. So, I can't use configure error output

Comment: If the column names are the same, you can map the fields from a datatable into Sql columns and use Sql Bulk copy to copy.
Eg: DataTable  dt;
using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
    }
}

Note: This would be the easiest method if you want to map all 300 fields from Sharepoint into Sql through the script task

Comment: As i said previously, my columns are different from source to destination.